# What is the best way to sync blog posts across multiple Magento sites?

Tags: blog

I have 8 Magento 1.9.2 sites on different domains. I want to have the ability to create a single post, centrally, that will automatically generate the same post on all 8 sites. The blog extension is currently **Blog - Community Edition**https://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/blog.html

At this point no blog posts have been made and I am trying to figure out an optimized solution before making any.

What kind of options would you guys recommend for implementing this?

Comment: I used iframe for this...

Answer (score 1):

**Bad solution**

Enable remote access on your shop database and use direct PHP/SQL scripts to move the data from shop to shop.

**Good solution**

Write an own extension for the source shop that extends the Magento REST- or SOAP-API. This module should provide API models for the blog post entity.
Then write another module that should be installed in all the target shops and which gets the data, for example with a cron job each X minutes.

**Another good solution**

Do it the other way round: create a blog-API in the target shops, and implement a button in the source-Magento-backend that enables the author to push a blog to the other sites.

Which one you chose depends on the exact processes and use case.

Comment: I am somewhat surprised no Magento extensions exist already for doing this.  I love the button idea - going to start planning the API for the target sites and configuring the php script for the source site backend button.  Thank you again, great idea.